# Django and Azure SQL key error 'deferrable' when start migrate command

Tags: python, django, azure, django-models, azure-sql-database

I try to connect Django to Azure SQL and have the error KeyError: deferrable when I start to migrate command.
I can't find a resolution for this issue.

I use this application:

```
asgiref==3.2.10
Django==3.1
django-mssql-backend==2.8.1
pyodbc==4.0.30
pytz==2020.1
sqlparse==0.3.1
```

and this is my config in settings.py:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
        'NAME': 'DBNAME',
        'USER': 'DBUSER',
        'PASSWORD': 'PASSWORD',
        'HOST': 'databasename.database.windows.net',
        'PORT': '1433',

        'OPTIONS': {
            'driver': 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server',
        },
    },
}
```

The error is when i try to run 'manage.py migrate`. Everything runs fine until the 8th step. Here's the output:

```
(venv) C:\Users\...\...\>python manage.py migrate     
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions
Running migrations:
  Applying contenttypes.0001_initial... OK
  Applying auth.0001_initial... OK
  Applying admin.0001_initial... OK
  Applying admin.0002_logentry_remove_auto_add... OK
  Applying admin.0003_logentry_add_action_flag_choices... OK
  Applying contenttypes.0002_remove_content_type_name... OK
  Applying auth.0002_alter_permission_name_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0003_alter_user_email_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0004_alter_user_username_opts... OK
  Applying auth.0005_alter_user_last_login_null... OK
  Applying auth.0006_require_contenttypes_0002... OK
  Applying auth.0007_alter_validators_add_error_messages... OK
  Applying auth.0008_alter_user_username_max_length...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\...\...\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\...\...\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\...\...\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 330, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\...\...\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 371, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\...\...\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 85, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\...\...\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 243, in handle
    post_migrate_state = executor.migrate(
  File "C:\Users\...\...\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 117, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "C:\Users\...\...\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 147, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "C:\Users\...\...\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 227, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "C:\Users\...\...\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\migration.py", line 124, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)    
  File "C:\Users\...\...\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\operations\fields.py", line 236, in database_forwards
    schema_editor.alter_field(from_model, from_field, to_field)
  File "C:\Users\...\...\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 571, in alter_field
    self._alter_field(model, old_field, new_field, old_type, new_type,
  File "C:\Users\...\...\lib\site-packages\sql_server\pyodbc\schema.py", line 479, in _alter_field
    self.execute(self._create_unique_sql(model, columns=[old_field.column]))
  File "C:\Users\...\...\lib\site-packages\sql_server\pyodbc\schema.py", line 861, in execute
    sql = str(sql)
  File "C:\Users\...\...\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\ddl_references.py", line 200, in __str__
    return self.template % self.parts
KeyError: 'deferrable'

(venv) C:\Users\...\...>
```

but if I connect to DB I see a table created a table from Django.

please help
Thanks!

Comment: Could you accept the answer if it helped? It will help others to find it more easily.

Answer (score 18):

`django-mssql-backend` currently supporting till **Django 3.0.10**. The temporary fix is to downgrade your Django version from **Django 3.1.x to 3.0.10**.

bug request raised here: https://github.com/ESSolutions/django-mssql-backend/issues/63

## Edited:

Another solution, use **Microsoft's official** Django support package to overcome all the issues, the support is very good.

https://github.com/microsoft/mssql-django

Comment: As of June 2021, the version support remains an issue. After I downgraded from 3.1 to **3.0.14**, this error went away.

Answer (score 14):

I ran in to this same issue today. Roll back to Django 3.0.x (I went back to 3.0.6) and then run your migrations.

I realize that's not a fix, but at least it's a work around to get you going. Once you migrate, you should be able to update back to 3.1 and it will run fine.

Comment: FYI... There will be one additional migration needed once you upgrade back to 3.1.

Comment: Many thanks! it's helped. maybe you can answer why i had this problem and will have problem with migration in the future?

Comment: Ran into same issue here. Pretty sure it's something with `django-mssql-backend`, which says it only supports up to 3.0. Rolling back to that did the trick. Migration did work fine on 3.1 when using SQLite instead.